# Display MYSQL resource pointer as hyperlink in PHP

Tags: php, fetch

I'm trying to display the result of an MYSQL select count as a hyperlink in PHP.

When I output the result as plain text it works with this line.

`Print"<th>Meeting count:</th> <td>".mysql_result($result2,0) . "</td> ";`

But when I try it in a hyperlink it either comes up with the resource pointer ID or completely blank.

Here's the line I'm trying using mysql_fetch_assoc at the moment.

```
$rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2,0);
Print "<td><a href='userprofile3.php?profileID=$profileID'>$rec</a></td>";
```

I have a feeling I'm missing a character in this line

The profileID is generated from my other query

```
$profileID = $info['userID'];
```

And here is the query where the count is generated

$result2 = mysql_query("select count(meetingCode)  FROM meeting where meeting.userID = $profileID      AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 5, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 12 
AND 22 
AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 7, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 1 
AND 12 
AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 9, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 01 
AND 31");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching an associative array using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (which, by the way, only takes one parameter! You're running without PHP errors, so you probably didn't see it). This is **NOT** a string/string-convertible variable.

However, what it does have is the name of all the columns in the format `$rec['columnName']`. I can't correct your code as I do not know the name of your columns, but it should be simple for you to edit your code. One thing, though - if you don't concatenate, you'lll need to use `{$rec['columnName']}`.

One last thing. All `mysql` functions have been deprecated in favour of PDO and MySQLi. Switch to them.

Comment: Hi thanks, Im querying the database from php to count how many valid meetings a user has based on the meeting code. I have this in a while loop that follows the user list and each time it loops puts the userID in my other query so it can count the meetings for that user then represent that as an integer hyperlink on the page. In this instance I can't see how referencing the column name in the database will help.

Comment: Edit your question and put the SQL query in, along with where the variable `$profileID` is generated. Whatever happens, you can't use an array as a string, so currently the text in the link should be blank or Array().

Comment: `$profileID` should still be set, unless you've unset it. As for `$rec`, change your query to this: `"select count(meetingCode) AS countMeetings FROM meeting where meeting.userID = $profileID AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 5, 2 ) BETWEEN 12 AND 22 AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 7, 2 ) BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND SUBSTRING( meetingCode, 9, 2 ) BETWEEN 01 AND 31"`. From there, you'll be able to access the count as `$rec['countMeetings']`.

Comment: Thank you yes! So the difference with this is it's assigning a mysql variable for the count, right?

Comment: I named the column, effectively, which allows you to get it back easily on the associative array regardless of its column order (I could've acquired it back using `$rec[0]`, but if you change your query and add a column before it, it'll fail. Chose the reliable option). Still... change to PDO! mysql_ functions are deprecated and will go away once PHP5.5 or PHP6 comes off the baking tray :-)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array, which you cannot output directly. Depending on your query, you want to do $rec['columnName'], e.g. SELECT name FROM users would give you $rec['name'].